# IntelliJ not stopping at breakpoints

Tags: unit-testing, debugging, intellij-idea

I am trying to debug my failing test case but IntelliJ won't stop at the breakpoints. It used to work for the same project, but it suddenly stopped working.

I tried to `Invalidate caches/Restart`, but sadly the test runs without going to debug mode.
I also tried to re-import my project by deleting the `.idea` folder. Same error persits.

Comment: Add more detail to what run configuraiton you are using, which breakpoint is not working exactly. Do they have check marks inside them when you launch debug? Make sure you have built the project before launching the debug. Also make sure the **Before launch** section has the `Build` step configured. If issue remains provide a sample project.